# Need help converting WCF netTcpBinding to CustomBinding

Tags: wcf

I need help converting the following netTcpBinding to an equivalent CustomBinding:

```
<bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="secureNetTcp" openTimeout="00:00:25" closeTimeout="00:00:27" receiveTimeout="00:10:10" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            listenBacklog="50" maxBufferPoolSize="2097152" maxBufferSize="2097152" maxConnections="50" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152">
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2097152" />
            <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="true" />
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                <message algorithmSuite="Basic256Sha256" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I'm mostly struggeling with the Security part of the custom binding, because I can't fathom all the different settings. And everything seems to be named differently as well (compared to netTcpBinding parameters).

In case it's necessary I'll provide the following information as well:
The service endpoint has a certificate attached to it via *serviceBehavior*.
In my code I provide a username/password when creating the proxy (service behavior has `<userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Windows" />` under *serviceCredentials*; For the netTcpBinding the WCF configuration editor shows `ClientCredentialType=Windows`, which I guess is the default value).

**Update:**

I have found a potential solution for my main problem - increasing *ChannelInitilizationTimeout* - without having to create a CustomBinding. I'll share this, incase someone stumbels upon this thread while googeling...

What I did was create a custom class that inherits from **NetTcpBinding** and in it's constructor used reflection to set the *ChannelInitilizationTimeout* property. Thus maintaining full compatibility with *NetTcpBinding*.

Here is the code for my custom class:

```
public class MyNetTcpBinding : NetTcpBinding
{
    public MyNetTcpBinding()
    {
        var fi = typeof(NetTcpBinding).GetField("transport", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        var val = (System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpTransportBindingElement)fi.GetValue(this);
        val.ChannelInitializationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    }
}

public class MyBindingElement : NetTcpBindingElement
{
    protected override Type BindingElementType
    {
        get { return typeof(MyNetTcpBinding); }
    }
}

public class MyBindingElementCollection : StandardBindingCollectionElement<MyNetTcpBinding, MyBindingElement>
{
}
```

After compiling this class (I created a seperate DLL project for this class), I used WCF configuration editor (under left pane "Configuration" -> Advanced -> Extensions -> binding extensions -> new -> give a name, eg. "**MyNetTcp**" and point to the dll file) to add my class as an extension to bindings.

Afterwards in WCF app.config just replace `netTcpBinding` with `MyNetTcp` (there are three references in total; one in `<service><endpoint binding="netTcpBinding"></endpoint></service>;` the other two are xml tags under `<bindings><netTcpBinding></netTcpBinding></bindings>`).

**I will leave this question open in case someone wants to give a proper answer to the original question...**

Comment: Not sure why any of the default bindings would not satisfy your needs, but I'd look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731172.aspx and this SOF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235931/wcf-how-to-create-programatically-custom-binding-with-binary-encoding-over-htt

Comment: @Bryan - I need to increase the ChannelInitilizationTimeout property, but that can only be done in a CustomBinding. (Sometimes my clients get an exception when opening a channel to the service, tracing showed that a Socket Initilization exception had occured due to a timeout (default 5 sec). How come my server (win 2003 R2, .net4, quad-core, 4GB ram) can't handle only 30 clients is beyond me...) If I could somehow set the property in c# code, eg. while creating the WCF service, that would satisfy me as well, but I haven't found a way to access the channel binding via code (I can only add new).

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure you cannot access that property via code.  I'm sure you've read this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreal/archive/2009/12/04/wcf-nettcpbinding-what-to-do-if-the-socket-did-not-complete-within-the-allotted-timeout-of.aspx and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751528.aspx and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731078.aspx.

Comment: @BryanCorazza - I had indeed already read the first two, the third one I hadn't read before. Still, none of those pages are helpful in regards to my problem (What is the equivalent of TransportWithMessageCredential in a CustomBinding? Is Windows authentication Kerberos or Username in a CustomBinding? Do in need to change any of the other 50 settings in CustomBinding to get an equivalent to my example? etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in the  netTcpBinding into a custom binding and do the following. 
There is no guarantee that reflection will work across versions.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajay/archive/2010/01/29/how-to-create-a-custom-binding-from-a-standardbinding.aspx

Comment: That Find<>() method is quite interesting. The only problem is, where do I plug this code into? The only option I currently see is during the creation of my ServiceHost, although I would have to define the entire endpoint+binding in code (can't use the config file like I do now), since it is only possible to add endpoints for a ServiceHost... (maybe it's possible to subclass the ServiceHost and override some create methods inorder to inject my CustomBinding based on the config files regular netTcpBinding, but I haven't looked into this)

Comment: I was referring to you code which uses reflection to update the property - This might be where you can create the custom binding. If you want part config and part code.

Again you can just create a custom binding as well with the TcpTransportBindingElement in config. 

We have bumped this up in 4.5 btw - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Also for servicehost extensibility you could try the serviceHostFactory and override ApplyConfiguration

Comment: It's not possible to use your method with my code (unless perhaps when overriding some method), because your method basically creates a new binding or at least new binding elements (I can't for instance in my class constructor redefine/recreate my class as a 'new CustomBinding()'). What I would really prefer is all config and no code, but since no one has posted a config based answer I have had to use my code solution, which I can plug into a config file as an extension. I guess I'll just wait for .net 4.5 inorder to revert back to netTcpBinding...